# What is the need of "actually" here

Tags: spoken-english

1. How SIM cards work?
2. How SIM cards **actually** work.

Is the word "actually" asking for **more precise answer?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking it up in a dictionary? What did you find?

Comment: **Actually** is used to suggest that the answer that follows is more accurate and informative than other answers might have been.